# Analytical Hierarchy Process (AHP) tool: Input layers do not have same grid extent

Tags: qgis, raster, saga

I am using this tool to create a suitability map for landfill site selection. However, when I gave the input raster layers, the .csv file for comparison table and run the tool, an error message saying- "Unable to execute algorithm - Input layers do not have same grid extent"

I infer from this that the size of all input layers must be same, but do not know if that can be done or not. And if yes, then how?